# alias in mongo db

Tags: java, mongodb

I've started to fiddle with mongo db and came up with a question.
Say, I have an object (POJO) with an id field (say, named 'ID') that I would like to represent in JSON and store/load in/from Mongo DB.
As far as I understood any object always has _id field (with underscore, lowercased).
What I would like to do is: during the query I would like the mongo db to return me my JSON with field ID instead of _id.
In SQL I would use something like

`SELECT _id as ID ...`

My question is whether its possible to do this in mongo db, and if it is, the Java based Example will be really appreciated :)

I understand that its possible to iterate over the records and substitute the _id with ID manually but I don't want this O(n) loop.
I also don't really want to duplicate the lines and store both "id" and "_id"
So I'm looking for solution at the level of query or maybe Java Driver.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've end up using the following approach in the Java Driver:

```
DBCursor cursor = runSomeQuery();
try {
        while(cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject dbObject  = cursor.next();
            ObjectId id = (ObjectId) dbObject.get("_id");
            dbObject.removeField("_id");
            dbObject.put("ID", id.toString());
            System.out.println(dbObject);
        }

    }   finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
```

I was wondering whether this is the best solution or I have other better options
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb doesnt use SQL , its more like Object Query Language and Collections.

what you can try is , some thing similar to below code using Mongo Java Driver

```
Pojo obj = new PojoInstance();
obj.setId(id);
db.yourdb.find(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks I know that mongo doesn't work with SQL, I just stated that If I were using SQL and some RDBMS server I would do the aforementioned select. I couldn't understand from the suggested solution how exactly mongo db works with objects (I guess you mean the Spring Data approach, they have an explicit @Id annotation if I'm not mistaken) and I'm using Mongo Java driver solution. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of what I am doing in Javascript.  It may be helpful to you.  In my case I am removing the _id field and aliasing the two very nested fields to display simpler names.

```
db.players.aggregate([
  { $match: { accountId: '12345'}},
  { $project: {
    "_id": 0,
    "id": "$id",
    "masterVersion": "$branches.master.configuration.player.template.version",
    "previewVersion": "$branches.preview.configuration.player.template.version"
    }
  }
])
```

I hope you find this helpful.